# Django custom save model creating duplicate files

Tags: django, django-models, save

I'm trying to get image uploads to also save as thumbnails, which works. The problem was when I did an update the custom method saved the thumbnail again in a different directory. so I modified my save function to look like this.

models.py

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y%m')
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='thumbnails/%Y%m')
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    year = models.ForeignKey(Year, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    people = TaggableManager(through=TaggedPeople, verbose_name='People')
    tags = TaggableManager(through=TaggedGeneric, verbose_name='Tags')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         try:
             this = Photo.objects.get(id=self.id)
             if this.thumbnail != self.thumbnail:
                 this.thumbnail.delete(save=False)
         except:
            if self.thumbnail:
                img = Image.open(BytesIO(self.thumbnail.read()))

                if hasattr(img, '_getexif'):
                    exif = img._getexif()
                    if exif:
                        for tag, label in ExifTags.TAGS.items():
                            if label == 'Orientation':
                                orientation = tag
                                break
                        if orientation in exif:
                            if exif[orientation] == 3:
                                img = img.rotate(180, expand=True)
                            elif exif[orientation] == 6:
                                img = img.rotate(270, expand=True)
                            elif exif[orientation] == 8:
                                img = img.rotate(90, expand=True)

                img.thumbnail((360,360), Image.ANTIALIAS)
                output = BytesIO()
                img.save(output, format='JPEG', quality=95)
                output.seek(0)
                self.thumbnail = File(output, self.thumbnail.name)

            return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

and my views

```
class PhotoCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Photo
    fields = ['image', 'title', 'description', 'year', 'people', 'tags']
    template_name = 'photoapp/create.html'
    success_url = '/photo/?page=1'
    extra_context = {'tags':GenericTag.objects.all().order_by('name'),'people':PeopleTag.objects.all().order_by('name'),}

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.thumbnail = self.request.FILES['image']
        form.instance.submitter = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

class PhotoUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    template_name = 'photoapp/update.html'
    model = Photo
    fields = ['title', 'description', 'year', 'people', 'tags']
    success_url = '/photo/?page=1'
```

So the CreateView now works fine, and I have stopped the duplicate thumbnail files, but the UpdateView does not work.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I just had to add a save to the try section.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         try:
             this = Photo.objects.get(id=self.id)
             if this.thumbnail != self.thumbnail:
                 this.thumbnail.delete(save=False)
             return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
         except:
            if self.thumbnail:
                img = Image.open(BytesIO(self.thumbnail.read()))

                if hasattr(img, '_getexif'):
                    exif = img._getexif()
                    if exif:
                        for tag, label in ExifTags.TAGS.items():
                            if label == 'Orientation':
                                orientation = tag
                                break
                        if orientation in exif:
                            if exif[orientation] == 3:
                                img = img.rotate(180, expand=True)
                            elif exif[orientation] == 6:
                                img = img.rotate(270, expand=True)
                            elif exif[orientation] == 8:
                                img = img.rotate(90, expand=True)

                img.thumbnail((360,360), Image.ANTIALIAS)
                output = BytesIO()
                img.save(output, format='JPEG', quality=95)
                output.seek(0)
                self.thumbnail = File(output, self.thumbnail.name)

            return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar complaint in Django-Wagtail, where saving image.save() programmatically duplicated on the file system the imported image. Do get around this I used [Python Glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to get the path, and OS to remove the original image after the save function had been loaded. It worked well enough for Wagtail, I wanted to capture the issue for others - as there isn't much on the web about this. It's frustrating, doubles your disk space usage due to this functionality if you aren't careful! I don't like that it renames the files/moves them, but it is what it is.

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from wagtail.images.models import Image
from django.core.files.images import ImageFile
import os
from os import path
import glob
#import sqlite3


class Command(BaseCommand):

help = "just a thing to "

def handle(self, *args, **options):

    target_path = "/home/inmyth/inmyth/media/images/"

    my_images = []

    if os.path.exists(target_path):
  
        my_images = glob.glob(target_path + "*.png")

        for mj_imgs in my_images:
            print(mj_imgs)
            image_file = ImageFile(open(mj_imgs, 'rb'), name=mj_imgs[:-4])
            img_label = mj_imgs.rfind("/") + 1
            image = Image(title=mj_imgs[img_label:-4], file=image_file)
            image.save()
            os.remove(mj_imgs)
    pass
```